# Como selecionar posições da matriz/ sorteio aleatório?

Tags: c, c++

Bom dia! Preciso fazer um sorteio aleatório dos elementos da matriz para saber se há um barco (barco=1). Assim como, no final de 10 tentativas preciso imprimir com (x) as posições bombardeadas com sucesso, tiros na água (-), água (A), navios intáctos (N).
Foi complicado, mas já consegui melhorar meu programa, mas ainda não compila está parte, por favor, se puderem me ajudar fico muito grato!

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 int main()
 {
char inimigo   [4][4] = {{0,1,1,0,}
                        {1,0,1,0},
                        {1,1,0,1},
                        {0,0,1,0}};


 char tabuleiro[4][4];
 int i,j;

for (i=0; i<4; i++){
 for(j=0; j<4; j++){
    tabuleiro[i][j] = '.';
    printf("%c", tabuleiro[i[j]);
}
printf("\n");
}
printf("Informe as coordenadas do tiro (linha/coluna):");
scanf("%d %d", &i &j);



}
```

Comment: Como está, acho que a pergunta é muito ampla porque a resposta correta é que escrevam o programa completo... Vai ser melhor se trabalhar isso em módulos (implementar matriz; sorteio; posicionar navios; atirar; etc) e vier trazendo dúvidas específicas sobre cada um deles.

Comment: Olá, a pergunta não tem como ser _cancelada_. Se ela não possuísse uma resposta com pontuação positiva poderia ser apagada, mas não é o caso. Sendo assim, eu sugeriria você deixar essa pergunta mais próxima da sua versão original o possível, de uma forma que não invalide a resposta existente, e ao criar uma nova questão que deixe bem claro a diferença para essa daqui.

Answer (score 6):

Isso é simples. Eu posso te dar o código mastigado, mas você que sabe.
Para escolher a matriz aleatoriamente você tem duas opções: a maneira certa e a maneira porca.

Na maneira certa, a ideia é iterar por cada membro da matriz, até que não haja uma matriz/ponteiro. No seu caso, você apenas tem dois membros então haverá apenas uma iteração. Após a primeira iteração (escolher um item aleatório), você seleciona *mais um*, seja este um dos "navios" (suponho que seja um booleano, 0 para ausência e 1 para presença).

Na maneira porca, você transforma todos esses dados em uma cadeia só de dados: Um único ponteiro de memória. Sabendo o espaço que essa cadeia inteira ocupa, você terá uma matriz uni-dimensional e poderá conseguir o valor desejado com apenas "uma iteração".

Tente fazer o código por si; aprenda. Se não conseguir pensar, [tenha uma mãozinha](http://pastebin.com/wpumh6bn).

Comment: Parabéns pela reposta, explicou bem e não entregou tudo de mão beijada..